# How to check if a date value inside an hash is bigger than a reference date

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a validation and I have an hash with this structure

```
elements.map{ |e| [e.id,e.coverable.published_at] }.to_h
=> {305=>Fri, 17 Apr 2020 15:23:00 CEST +02:00,
 306=>Fri, 17 Apr 2020 13:00:00 CEST +02:00,
 307=>Fri, 17 Apr 2020 09:20:00 CEST +02:00,
 308=>Fri, 17 Apr 2020 12:59:00 CEST +02:00,
 309=>Fri, 17 Apr 2020 11:39:00 CEST +02:00}
```

I have a reference date...

```
published_at
=> Mon, 04 May 2020 23:51:00 CEST +02:00
```

I have to check if any of the element has a `published_at` datetime value bigger than my `published_at`.
Is there a short way to do that?

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We'd like to see your attempt to solve this. Without that evidence of effort it looks like you didn't try and want us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
elements.any? { |e| e.coverable.published_at > your_published_at }
```

In case you need the element which passes the condition use find

```
element = elements.find { |e| e.coverable.published_at > your_published_at }
# if element is not nil such element is present
```